# AngularJS - Include variable in a callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular directive that allows a callback to be passed in the following manner:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('myDirective', myDirective);

function myDirective() {
    return {
        bindToController: {
            buttonClick: '&'
        },
        controller: 'MyController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: '<div><button data-ng-click="vm.buttonClick(\'hello\')">Click me</button>'
    };
}
```

Then in my parent HTML, I have

```
<my-directive button-click="ctrl.myCallback()"></my-directive>
```

Then finally in my parent controller, I have

```
function myCallback(msg) {
    alert('message is: ' + msg);
}
```

The goal is to display "hello" or whatever data was passed to the callback, however this is not working.

Am I doing something wrong? It works when no arguments are specified

Thanks

FYI here is link to Plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/F6TafMWD3EWqVCCLaMys?p=preview)

Comment: Can you show `MyController` code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `&`, you need to call the function with 1 argument which is a map of the arguments you want to pass.

```
<my-directive button-click="ctrl.myCallback(msg})"></my-directive>

return {
    //...
    template: '<div><button data-ng-click="vm.buttonClick({msg: \'hello\'})">Click me</button>'
}
```

If your function took 2 arguments, you would have:

```
<my-directive button-click="ctrl.myCallback(msg1, msg2})"></my-directive>

return {
    //...
    template: '<div><button data-ng-click="vm.buttonClick({msg1: \'hello\', msg2: '\'there\'})">Click me</button>'
}

function myCallback(msg1, msg2) {
    alert('message is: ' + msg1 + ' ' + msg2);
}
```

This GIST is pretty exhaustive regarding directive binding: https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/6282750

Take a look at point 8

Another good resource is: https://thinkster.io/egghead/isolate-scope-am

UPDATE: I updated and fixed your plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/W4RnZeCaxfCbVcYeKXLD?p=preview

- Be careful to select angular version 1.x
- your directive controller must be a function if you use `bindToController`. An empty function is OK
- Look carefully at how I named the variable for calling the `myCallback` and compare it with this second plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/OvCXC0jeycIOxyoQ0R9w?p=preview Let me know if you need more explanation regarding this point in particular.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `template` not `templateUrl`?

Comment: Yes, it's fixed. Thanks

Comment: Wanted to give link to video https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-isolate-scope-expression-binding , but thinkster has the same content and even references egghead.

Comment: Thanks @apairet. I've made the modification, however `function myCallback(args)` is telling me that my `args` is empty. Have I missed something? I will try to post an example shortly

Comment: Here is a link to my Plunker: (http://plnkr.co/edit/F6TafMWD3EWqVCCLaMys?p=preview) @apairet

Comment: I will have a look and come back to you

Comment: @Ricky I just updated my answer and linked to 2 working plunkr. Hope this clears everything :-)

Comment: THANK YOU @apairet. This does exactly what I wanted. I'm curious, where did I go wrong? It seems that the variable name passed in `ctrl.parentCallback` needs to match the variable used in the directive HTML code. Why is this the case (in your example the variable is `yourKey`)

Comment: Also... To pass multiple variables, here is what I did: `<button data-ng-click="vm.myCallback({yourKey: {msg: \'hello\', value:\'123\'}})">Call Callback</button>`. Can you advise if this is the correct approach? @apairet. Thanks again

Comment: I would do `vm.myCallback({msg: \'hello\', value:\'123\'})` but this is just a matter of taste. I personally find it more readable. The markup then must be `<my-directive my-callback="ctrl.myCallback(msg, value)"></my-directive>` and the parentController function must then take 2 arguments. `function myCallback(arg1, arg2) {//do something with arg1 and arg2}`

Answer (score 0):

Look this example. Use $compile for bind events scope

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('MyController', function($scope){
    $scope.buttonClick = function(msg ){
      console.log(msg);
       $scope.msg = msg;
    };
}).directive('directive', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        link : function(scope, element){
            
                var content = $compile('<div><button type="button" ng-click="buttonClick(' + "'Test Msg'" + ')">Click me</button> {{msg}}')(scope);
                element.append(content);
            
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyController">
   <directive></directive>
</div>
```